# Better way to randomize from text file in Powershell

Tags: function, powershell, random, text

I have a working Powershell function that uses the System.Speech to read-out a random line from a text file, using the Get-Random cmdlet.

Unfortunately, the randomizer cmdlet doesn't seem to be doing such a good job by itself, as it repeats the same lines **way** too many times.

My text file contains just sentences.

```
function suggestion{
    $suggestion=(Get-Random -InputObject (get-content C:\Tools\linesoftext.txt))
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Speech 
    $synth = New-Object -TypeName System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
    $synth.Speak($suggestion)
    }
```

I'm not sure if I can modify what I have, or rethink the way I'm trying to randomize the output--maybe by keeping track of what has been already played and loop?  (I'm a bit stumped).

Comment: In which context are you defining and executing this function? Loading it from your profile and using it at random? Using it in a GUI application? What's the context?

Comment: I'm loading it to my $profile and calling it from a Powershell command prompt.  Each time I call the "suggestion" function, I get a random line spoken to me by the system.

Comment: The output you are getting now _is_ randomized (as determined by the `Get-Random` cmdlet, which is really pseudo-random). It sounds like you are saying "`Get-Random` isn't random enough for me based on my anecdotal observations," which isn't really an accurate measurement of pseudo-randomness.

Comment: @l0c0b0x It sounds more like you want to *shuffle* the order in which the sentences are spoken, would you agree?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, Sure!  What I don't want though is to repeat the lines until the last line has being shared.  If that makes sense.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I see what your saying, and it is anecdotal--but I ran it about 30 times and within those 30 times, it repeated the same line 6 times (I have 36 lines in the text file).

Comment: My point is that there's no guarantee that `Get-Random` will produce an order that is in accordance with what seems random enough to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Mathias's suggestion of shuffling the lines at launch, but if you want to keep in the motif of randomly selecting a line, but just don't want to hear the same lines over and over again set a threshold that it won't repeat at and store that many items in a global variable, and then add the last spoken line to it, and remove the first item whenever you have it speak a line. Something like:

```
function suggestion{
    $lines = get-content C:\Tools\linesoftext.txt
    $suggestion= Get-Random -InputObject ($lines | Where{$_ -notin $global:RecentSuggestions})
    [array]$global:RecentSuggestions += $suggestion
    If($global:RecentSuggestions.count -gt 20){$global:RecentSuggestions = $global:RecentSuggestions | Select -Skip 1}
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Speech 
    $synth = New-Object -TypeName System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
    $synth.Speak($suggestion)
    }
```

That'll keep track of up to 20 lines, and exclude those from the list of lines to randomly select from.

Comment: Nice! I like it :-D

Answer (score 1):

> I'm loading it to my $profile and calling it from a Powershell command prompt.

In this case you could use your profile to read the lines into memory and then randomly *shuffle* them, this way the same line won't repeat. To advance through the list, you could employ a `ScriptProperty`, like so:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Speech -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# One synthesizer on per shell should be enough 
$__synth = New-Object -TypeName System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer

# Read lines of text into memory, shuffle their order
$__lines = Get-Content C:\Tools\linesoftext.txt |Sort-Object {Get-Random}

# Add a script property to the $__lines variable that always returns the next sentence
$ScriptProperty = @{
  Name = 'NextSentence'
  MemberType = 'ScriptProperty' 
  Value = {
    return $this[++$global:__idx % @($this).Count]
  }
}
Add-Member @ScriptProperty -InputObject $__lines 

# Speak the next sentence
function Get-Suggestion {
  $global:__synth.Speak($global:__lines.NextSentence)
}

# Define alias `suggestion -> Get-Suggestion`
Set-Alias suggestion Get-Suggestion
```